# Knowing if any key is pressed, wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a timer, and need to know if any of the keys is pressed on any cycle. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Windows, Use [PyHook](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pyhook/index.php?title=Main_Page) If you like to know system wide key press events.

```
import pythoncom, pyHook 

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    print 'Ascii:', event.Ascii, chr(event.Ascii)
    print 'Key:', event.Key
    print 'KeyID:', event.KeyID
    print 'ScanCode:', event.ScanCode
    print 'Extended:', event.Extended

    return True #for pass through key events, False to eat Keys

hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
hm.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Linux it's found in the `curses` module, if you use Windows it's in the `msvcrt` module.
I found following article really helpful in describing this topic - [Event Driven Programming](http://www.freenetpages.co.uk/hp/alan.gauld/tutevent.htm)

Comment: msvcrt.getch() seems to crash my wx application

Comment: Either post a traceback information or give more detail on what is going on in code. Even using `msvcrt`, you will need to write event handlers and call them from within your timer loop. However, considering your comment about background execution, `msvcrt` should be what you are looking for. You will just need to figure out how to use it in your particular case.

Comment: there's no traceback, my application just locks up.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import sys
c = sys.stdin.read(1)
```